# amadeus API list of all possible hotel "amenities"

Tags: api, amadeus

In Amadeus hotels API there is amenities choices and in the search results there is different possibilities as well.

To make amenities more user readable I'd like a FULL list of ALL different possible amenities so that I can populate a database with amenities code and different translations.

For a client searching for hotels: stuff like ACC_BATHS, SAFE_DEP_BOX is kind of not readable friendly...

I'm referring to this

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "hotel-offers",
      "hotel": {
        "type": "hotel",
        "cityCode": "MIA",
        ...
        "amenities": [
          "HANDICAP_FAC",
          "ACC_BATHS",
          "ACC_WASHBASIN",
          "ACC_BATH_CTRLS",
          "ACC_LIGHT_
```

where can I find a csv of all amenities ?

Answer (score 2):

I contacted the Amadeus tech support and they answered me this :

(you can copy this list, it's csv format... NAME_OF_AMENITY,amenity_code )

226 codes

```
PHOTOCOPIER,BUS.2
PRINTER,BUS.28
AUDIO-VIS_EQT,BUS.37
WHITE/BLACKBOARD,BUS.38
BUSINESS_CENTER,BUS.39
CELLULAR_PHONE_RENTAL,BUS.40
COMPUTER_RENTAL,BUS.41
EXECUTIVE_DESK,BUS.42
LCD/PROJECTOR,BUS.45
MEETING_ROOMS,BUS.46
OVERHEAD_PROJECTOR,BUS.48
SECRETARIAL_SERVICES,BUS.49
CONFERENCE_SUITE,BUS.94
CONVENTION_CTR,BUS.95
MEETING_FACILITIES,BUS.96
24_HOUR_FRONT_DESK,HAC.1
DISABLED_FACILITIES,HAC.101
MULTILINGUAL_STAFF,HAC.103
WEDDING_SERVICES,HAC.104
BANQUETING_FACILITIES,HAC.105
PORTER/BELLBOY,HAC.106
BEAUTY_PARLOUR,HAC.107
WOMENS_GST_RMS,HAC.110
PHARMACY,HAC.111
120_AC,HAC.113
120_DC,HAC.114
220_AC,HAC.115
220_DC,HAC.117
BARBECUE,HAC.118
BUTLER_SERVICE,HAC.136
CAR_RENTAL,HAC.15
CASINO,HAC.16
BAR,HAC.165
LOUNGE,HAC.165
TRANSPORTATION,HAC.172
WIFI,HAC.178
WIRELESS_CONNECTIVITY,HAC.179
BALLROOM,HAC.191
BUS_PARKING,HAC.192
CHILDRENS_PLAY_AREA,HAC.193
NURSERY,HAC.194
DISCO,HAC.195
24_HOUR_ROOM_SERVICE,HAC.2
COFFEE_SHOP,HAC.20
BAGGAGE_STORAGE,HAC.201
NO_KID_ALLOWED,HAC.217
KIDS_WELCOME,HAC.218
COURTESY_CAR,HAC.219
CONCIERGE,HAC.22
NO_PORN_FILMS,HAC.220
INT_HOTSPOTS,HAC.221
FREE_INTERNET,HAC.222
INTERNET_SERVICES,HAC.223
PETS_ALLOWED,HAC.224
FREE_BREAKFAST,HAC.227
CONFERENCE_FACILITIES,HAC.24
HI_INTERNET,HAC.259
EXCHANGE_FAC,HAC.26
LOBBY,HAC.276
DOCTOR_ON_CALL,HAC.28
24H_COFFEE_SHOP,HAC.281
AIRPORT_SHUTTLE,HAC.282
LUGGAGE_SERVICE,HAC.283
PIANO_BAR,HAC.284
VIP_SECURITY,HAC.285
DRIVING_RANGE,HAC.30
DUTY_FREE_SHOP,HAC.32
ELEVATOR,HAC.33
EXECUTIVE_FLR,HAC.34
GYM,HAC.35
EXPRESS_CHECK_IN,HAC.36
EXPRESS_CHECK_OUT,HAC.37
FLORIST,HAC.39
CONNECTING_ROOMS,HAC.4
FREE_AIRPORT_SHUTTLE,HAC.41
FREE_PARKING,HAC.42
FREE_TRANSPORTATION,HAC.43
GAMES_ROOM,HAC.44
GIFT_SHOP,HAC.45
HAIRDRESSER,HAC.46
ICE_MACHINES,HAC.52
GARAGE_PARKING,HAC.53
JACUZZI,HAC.55
JOGGING_TRACK,HAC.56
KENNELS,HAC.57
LAUNDRY_SVC,HAC.58
AIRLINE_DESK,HAC.6
LIVE_ENTERTAINMENT,HAC.60
MASSAGE,HAC.61
NIGHT_CLUB,HAC.62
SWIMMING_POOL,HAC.66
PARKING,HAC.68
ATM/CASH_MACHINE,HAC.7
POOLSIDE_SNACK_BAR,HAC.72
RESTAURANT,HAC.76
ROOM_SERVICE,HAC.77
SAFE_DEP_BOX,HAC.78
SAUNA,HAC.79
BABY-SITTING,HAC.8
SOLARIUM,HAC.83
SPA,HAC.84
CONVENIENCE_STOR,HAC.88
PICNIC_AREA,HAC.9
THEATRE_DESK,HAC.90
TOUR_DESK,HAC.91
TRANSLATION_SERVICES,HAC.92
TRAVEL_AGENCY,HAC.93
VALET_PARKING,HAC.97
VENDING_MACHINES,HAC.98
TELECONFERENCE,MRC.121
VOLTAGE_AVAILABLE,MRC.123
NATURAL_DAYLIGHT,MRC.126
GROUP_RATES,MRC.141
INTERNET-HIGH_SPEED,MRC.17
VIDEO_CONF_FACILITIES,MRC.53
ACC_BATHS,PHY.102
BR/L_PRINT_LIT,PHY.103
ADAPT_RM_DOORS,PHY.104
ACC_RM_WCHAIR,PHY.105
SERV_SPEC_MENU,PHY.106
WIDE_ENTRANCE,PHY.107
WIDE_CORRIDORS,PHY.108
WIDE_REST_ENT,PHY.109
ACC_LIGHT_SW,PHY.15
ACC_WCHAIR,PHY.28
SERV_DOGS_ALWD,PHY.29
ACC_WASHBASIN,PHY.3
ACC_TOILETS,PHY.32
ADAPT_BATHROOM,PHY.38
HANDRAIL_BTHRM,PHY.38
ADAPTED_PHONES,PHY.39
ACC_ELEVATORS,PHY.42
TV_SUB/CAPTION,PHY.45
DIS_PARKG,PHY.50
EMERG_COD/BUT,PHY.57
HANDICAP_FAC,PHY.6
DIS_EMERG_PLAN,PHY.60
HEAR_IND_LOOPS,PHY.65
BR/L_PRNT_MENU,PHY.66
DIS_TRAIN_STAF,PHY.71
PIL_ALARMS_AVL,PHY.76
ACC_BATH_CTRLS,PHY.79
PUTTING_GREEN,REC.5
TROUSER_PRESS,RMA.111
VIDEO,RMA.116
GAMES_SYSTEM_IN_ROOM,RMA.117
VOICEMAIL_IN_ROOM,RMA.118
WAKEUP_SERVICE,RMA.119
WI-FI_IN_ROOM,RMA.123
CD_PLAYER,RMA.129
BATH,RMA.13
MOVIE_CHANNELS,RMA.139
SHOWER,RMA.142
OUTLET_ADAPTERS,RMA.159
BIDET,RMA.16
DVD_PLAYER,RMA.163
CABLE_TELEVISION,RMA.18
OVERSIZED_ROOMS,RMA.185
TEA/COFFEE_MK_FACILITIES,RMA.19
AIR_CONDITIONING,RMA.2
TELEVISION,RMA.20
ANNEX_ROOM,RMA.204
FREE_NEWSPAPER,RMA.205
HONEYMOON_SUITES,RMA.206
INTERNETFREE_HIGH_IN_RM,RMA.207
MAID_SERVICE,RMA.208
PC_HOOKUP_INRM,RMA.209
PC_IN_ROOM,RMA.21
SATELLITE_TV,RMA.210
VIP_ROOMS,RMA.211
CORDLESS_PHONE,RMA.25
CRIBS_AVAILABLE,RMA.26
ALARM_CLOCK,RMA.3
PHONE-DIR_DIAL,RMA.31
FAX_FAC_INROOM,RMA.38
FREE_LOCAL_CALLS,RMA.45
HAIR_DRYER,RMA.50
INTERNET-HI_SPEED_IN_RM,RMA.51
IRON/IRON_BOARD,RMA.55
KITCHEN,RMA.59
BABY_LISTENING_DEVICE,RMA.6
LAUNDRY_EQUIPMENT_IN_ROOM,RMA.66
MICROWAVE,RMA.68
MINIBAR,RMA.69
NONSMOKING_RMS,RMA.74
REFRIGERATOR,RMA.88
ROLLAWAY_BEDS,RMA.91
SAFE,RMA.92
WATER_SPORTS,RST.110
ANIMAL_WATCHING,RST.126
BIRD_WATCHING,RST.127
SIGHTSEEING,RST.142
BEACH_WITH_DIRECT_ACCESS,RST.155
SKI_IN/OUT,RST.156
TENNIS_PROFESSIONAL,RST.157
FISHING,RST.20
GOLF,RST.27
FITNESS_CENTER,RST.36
BEACH,RST.5
HORSE_RIDING,RST.61
INDOOR_TENNIS,RST.62
MINIATURE_GOLF,RST.67
BOATING,RST.7
TENNIS,RST.71
SCUBA_DIVING,RST.82
SKEET_SHOOTING,RST.85
SNOW_SKIING,RST.88
BOWLING,RST.9
VOLLEYBALL,RST.98
ELEC_GENERATOR,SEC.15
EMERG_LIGHTING,SEC.19
FIRE_DETECTORS,SEC.22
GUARDED_PARKG,SEC.34
RESTRIC_RM_ACC,SEC.39
EXT_ROOM_ENTRY,SEC.40
INT_ROOM_ENTRY,SEC.41
SMOKE_DETECTOR,SEC.50
ROOMS_WITH_BALCONIES,SEC.51
SPRINKLERS,SEC.54
FIRST_AID_STAF,SEC.57
SECURITY_GUARD,SEC.58
VIDEO_SURVEIL,SEC.62
EXTINGUISHERS,SEC.89
FIRE_SAFETY,SEC.9
FEMA_FIRE_SAFETY_COMPLIANT,SEC.93
FIRE_SAF_NOT_STANDARD,SEC.95
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the API, you can filter the offers by amenities:

https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/hotel/api-doc/hotel-search/api-reference

I assume the multiple select list in the amenities property contains all the items you need.

EDIT: I noticed that unfortunately, the response example contains additional values, apart from the input. So the input is not enough.